# FishEye REST API get reviews for changeset

Tags: atlassian-fisheye

I am trying to get list of reviews for specific changeset using FishEye REST API.

Here is my URL:

http://fisheye.company.com/rest-service-fe/search-v1/reviewsForChangesets/NameOfRepository/

I am posting it using fiddler composer with following request body:
cs=16964

Here is my response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
  <reviewsForChangesets>
     <changesets>
        <changeset>
           <reviews/>
           <changesetId>16964</changesetId>
        </changeset>
     </changesets>
</reviewsForChangesets>
```

As you can see it has no reviews information. However if I go to following url I can see that 16964 changeset has reviews assigned to it:

http://fisheye.company.com/changelog/NameOfRepository?cs=16964

I also tried to use:

http://fisheye.company.com/rest-service-fe/search-v1/reviewsForChangeset/NameOfRepository/

I got the same response. Am I missing something?